# Nightwatch testing: Set browser to fixed size

Tags: selenium, testing, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

Is there any way to ensure that the browser does not change from the initial window size. There are several things that are clicked during testing that are causing the window to maximize but i would like it to stay the same size throughout.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

set it up once and for all in your env configuration (under [`test_settings`](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/configuration/settings.html#test-session-settings) in the nightwatch config file):

```json
"desiredCapabilities": {
    "chromeOptions": {
        "args": [
            "window-size=1280,800"
        ]
    }
}
```

note that this method will work because we're setting a chrome flag, so implementation may vary (e.g. safari does not have such flags).

for browsers that do not support these options, it's best to resize the window [imperatively](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/resizeWindow.html) in the *globals `beforeEach` hook*:

```js
{
    beforeEach: function (browser, done) {
        browser.resizeWindow(1280, 800, done);
    }
}
```

have a read on the [nightwatch settings docs](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/configuration/settings.html#base-settings) to see how globals are used.

using the above methods, you *won't have to specify it in each test* :)

Comment: did you mean `browser.resizeWindow(1280, 800, done)`? you're right than, i updated the answer..

Comment: I did - whoops! Good of you to update it. Cheers. Deleted original comment so as not to confuse people with the wrong suggestion. See @Eliran Makla's comment

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 13):

You can fix the screen size before each test like that :

```
module.exports = {
  tags: ['myTest'],
  before : function (browser) {
    browser.resizeWindow(800, 600);
  },
  'Test #1' : function (browser) {
    return browser
      .url('http://localhost/test1')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000); 
  },
  'Test #2' : function (browser) {
    return browser
      .url('http://localhost/test2')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000); 
  },
  after : function (browser) {
    browser.end();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the firefox fix they should approve the pr, and it will work,
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/pull/2169